# How can I use the Python Tools for Visual Studio mixed mode debugger with Enthought Canopy Distribution?

Tags: python, visual-studio, enthought, canopy, ptvs

I use Enthought Canopy as my python distribution due to its suitability for scientific computation. However, I use [pytools](https://pytools.codeplex.com/) in Visual Studio as my IDE primarily because of its superior debugging compared to other IDEs for Windows.

Since version 2.0, pytools provides a native C-debugger ([mixed mode debugger](https://pytools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Mixed-mode%20debugging) or MMD) which is very useful for debugging when utilizing cython or including some native C code, and is also supposed to be *much faster* than the standard debugger, which makes it feasible to debug computationally expensive code, which would otherwise run too slow with debugging enabled.

Unfortunately the pytools MMD [requires debug symbols](https://pytools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Symbols%20for%20Python%20mixed-mode%20debugging) to work, which are available for the standard python distribution, however they note that

> If you're using a third-party Python distribution such as ActiveState
>   Python or Enthought Canopy, you will need to contact the authors of
>   that distribution to provide you with symbols.

I have not been able to find these debug symbols available anywhere from Enthought, so I want to know:

a) Do Enthought plan to make the debug symbols available for pytools users

b) If not, what are some possible workarounds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enthought Canopy 1.2, to be released later this month, includes full PTVS integration including debug symbols.

Comment: So how do we use the MMD with Canopy 1.2? Where are the debug symbols? By the way, Canopy continues to be shown as "Python 64-bit 2.7" for me, not "Enthought Canopy" as written in the release notes.

Comment: Sorry! Does this help, Tim? https://support.enthought.com/entries/25693245-PTVS-Python-Tools-for-Visual-Studio-requires-clean-install-of-Canopy-1-2- (With this, PTVS should find the debug symbols automatically.)

Comment: OK now PTVS has a new environment available: "Enthought Canopy (2.7 64-bit)", which I set as the default environment. However, when I enable the mixed mode debugger, it still shows the same "Python Symbols Required" dialog. Opening symbol settings gives a message [No debugging information](http://imgur.com/tF9Cx1Q).   FYI, I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and PTVS 2.0 RTM

Comment: So debug symbols seem to be in  `C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\Scripts`. Manually adding this directory makes everything start working; automatic detection doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 3):

(I'm the PTVS developer who wrote mixed-mode debugger for 2.0)

The requirement for symbols is a hard requirement, unfortunately - it's at the core of how the debugger works. So the only workaround is to use Python binaries that have symbols available for them - either stock ones from python.org, or building them yourself.   This only pertains to python??.dll, and, if you want ctypes stepping support, _ctypes.pyd.

I do not know whether Enthought build of Python is significantly different from regular Python, or whether they are drop-in compatible. But it may be worth a try as a workaround.